# Set country while scraping Amazon

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, crawlera

I'm scraping prices from Amazon,Everything works fine except I'm facing an issue of location,apparently some products are not available outside of US so when my program runs it fails to fetch prices, I'm using Crawlera for US IP proxy, but it still fails for few requests.

Is there any way I can lock it US,using sending Cookies or Something like that.Any help or reference would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Crawlera, you can create a new account through the web interface and set the region to US. Then replace your API key with the key for your newly created account.

See [this](https://support.scrapinghub.com/support/solutions/articles/22000188398-restricting-crawlera-ips-to-a-specific-region) guide for reference.